# HBase "two columns in one" feature

Tags: hbase

The following book implies that there is a way to put two columns in one without using column families. Is it an actual HBase feature or is it just a dev hack like "concatenate two values in one column before sending them to Hbase and I will remember that it is in fact two columns I put there"-hack? If this is a feature, what is the syntax for that?

> "Hadoop Application Architectures by Mark Grover, Ted Malaska,
>   Jonathan Seidman, and Gwen Shapira (O’Reilly)." :
>
> [When setting two columns foo and bar to a record,] each logical
>   record in the HBase table will have two rows in the HBase HFile
>   format. Here is the structure of such an HFile on disk:
>
> ```
> |RowKey |TimeStamp  |Column |Value
> |101    |1395531114 |F      |A1
> |101    |1395531114 |B      |B1
> ```
>
> The alternative choice is to have both the values from foo and bar in
>   the same HBase column. This would apply to all records of the table
>   and bears the following characteristics:
>
> - Both the columns would be retrieved at the same time. You may choose to disregard the value of the other column if you don’t need
>     it.
> - Both the column values would need to be updated together since they are stored as a single entity (column).
> - Both the columns would age out together based on the last update.
>
> Here is the structure of the HFile in such a case:
>
> ```
> |RowKey |TimeStamp  |Column |Value
> |101    |1395531114 |X      |A1|B1
> ```

I think it is different from putting multiple values in one columns as seen in [HBase storing data for a particular column with 2 or more values for the same row-key in Scala/Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42449609/hbase-storing-data-for-a-particular-column-with-2-or-more-values-for-the-same-ro) and see them as "versions" of the value because here he speaks about foo and bar being two different columns with two different roles. I found no mention of such a feature in the Hbase documentation https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#schema.

Comment: This is obviously just a hack, HBase does not support such a feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do this using value arrays for HBase value. After getting array value, you should split and use. I don't think there is another way to store multiple values in a single column family.